# How to update state of component provider using the Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-context

What is the method for mutating context in a child component in a function?

I've read a post on [mutating context from children](https://tinkerylabs.com/react-context-api-with-hooks/#mutating-context-from-children) which explains how to do it via a simple event handler. i.e.:

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
  <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>parent button +1</button>
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

But instead, I would like to update a function of the parent component (using context) in a child components function.

It is possible by passing that function around as a callback.

```
public anotherFunction(count, setCount) {
  // use the setCount here
  setCount(count + 1)
}

public handleClick(setCount) {
  // ..do some stuff to get the count
  let count = 10;
  this.anotherFunction(count, setCount);
}

render() {
  return(
    <MyContext.Consumer>
      <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(setCount)}>parent button +1</button>
    </MyContext.Consumer>
  )
}
```

Now this example works. However, having to pass through the `setCount` function in all the functions seems extraneous. Would something similar to this be possible?

```
public anotherFunction(count) {
  // perhaps something like this: 
  this.context.setCount(count + 1) // <- this doesn't work..
}

public handleClick() {
  // ..do some stuff to get the count
  let count = 10;
  this.anotherFunction(count);
}

render() {
  return(
    <MyContext.Consumer>
      <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>parent button +1</button>
    </MyContext.Consumer>
  )
}
```

Is there another better way to do this?

I've created a sandbox to demonstrate the example of the usage in the function more clearly:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/suspicious-jackson-y3tk4?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FMyForm.tsx

Comment: You can directly call the setCount function in handleClick(), why do you need anotherFunction?

Comment: It's clear that that works :). This is just an example. But in the 'real world' example some additional stuff is done in a function. The codesandbox is closer to the actual code.

Comment: I have given the solution for that, let me know if that works for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Generic implementation of context api -

In Provider -

```
this.state = {
      count: 0
    }

testFunction = (count) => {
// do whatever you want to do 
  this.setState({
    count: count + 1;
})

<AppContext.Provider
        value={{
         testFunction: this.testFunction,
        }}>
        <App />
      </AppContext.Provider>
```

In Consumer -

```
export default props => (
    <AppContext.Consumer>
        {({testFunction}) => (
          <ChildComponent testFunction={testFunction} />
        )}
      </AppContext.Consumer>
);
```

and then,

```
export class ChildComponent extends React.Component { 
  // your component here

public anotherFunction(count) {
  // perhaps something like this: 
  const {testFunction} = this.props;
  testFunction(count);
}

public handleClick() {
  // ..do some stuff to get the count
  let count = 10;
  this.anotherFunction(count);
}

render() {
  return(
      <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>parent button +1</button>
  )
}
}
```

pass the function as a prop to the component and use it directly where you want to use instead of passing it as a parameter from one function to another :-)

Comment: Thanks. Not quite it though I think. The idea is that in this example the testFunction, would have a trigger that could potentially trigger the function that is defined in the context.

Comment: I have updated my answer using the testFunction (defined in Provider) to be used from the Consumer

Comment: When you will pass it as a prop and use it in consumer then it will actually be executed from the provider. (just like a prop function).